# Qt for iOS: Error unknown module(s) in Qt: webkitwidgets

Tags: ios, qt

I have downloaded .dmg file for Qt on Android and iOS. I have installed it and tried to run examples. I am able to run examples under folder "widgets" for iOS but when I try to run example for "webkitwidgets" and run qmake on (let say for example of "browser") .pro (in this case for example browser.pro) then it gives me error : "Error unknown module(s) in Qt: webkitwidgets". Then I checked "ios" folder in installed qt directory. I found in "Include" folder there is no folder called "QtWebkitWidgets" while there is folder "QtWidgets". Let me know solution asap because I am doing some poc on Qt for iOS and need to have conclusion soon. Did I miss some steps while installation or do I have to do some extra steps to execute examples for QtWebkitWidgets. Let me know whether QtWebkitWidgets module is supported for in Qt for iOS or not. Note that I am using Qt 5.2 with XCode 5. If more detail is required then let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Apple explicitly forbids that any programming language be compiled/interpreted on the iOS device itself, except by their own WebKit. So Qt’s WebKit is disallowed.
It is worthy to note thet part of the QtWebKit team has started the project QtWebEngine to explore the option of providing a Chromium/Blink based web engine instead of QtWebKit, and in addition to that, the iOS port of Qt will need their own webview API since Apple does not allow additional web engines on their iOS devices.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Just have another question to solve my problem. However I will post it as separate question also. My question is can I open UIWebView(iOS component) from Qt application? Is there any way to do so?If it is possible then I will create rest of application in Qt and for opening HTML component I can open UIWebView.

Comment: It’s possible (with the Qt4iOS iOS plugin) to use UIWebView from QWidget based apps, but not QML apps. The Digia iOS plugin does not support using UIWebView in any way (and won’t any time soon).

Comment: @Nejat anything new on that topic? Is it possible to create a workaround?